# GitHub different history of commits

Tags: git, github

I found interesting situation
I check github ,when i checked history of commits of the folder i see some commits for file which are not exists in the history of these file, they are missed in file but exist in history of folder

Comment: How did you check the "history of commits of the folder"? Github doesn't show folder history, just file history...

Comment: Very easy . When you are looking source code, you can enter the folder, and see at the top on right link history for example history of commits of folder 'models'   https://github.com/vladimircape/project/commits/master/protected/models